# Issues Implementing Material Design in Bundle

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, bottom-sheet

I am trying to make a bottom sheet; the code seems correct but I am having issues with the build.gradle. I am having trouble when I try to  add in `implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$material_version"`. I receive the error 
"Could not get unknown property `'material_version' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.`"
Any assistance would be appreciated

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bottom_sheet"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$material_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

BottomSheetActivity.kt

```
class BottomSheetActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var standardBottomSheetBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<View>

    private val startColor = Color.parseColor("#00FFFFFF")
    private val endColor = Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF")
    private val textColor = Color.parseColor("#FF000000")

    private var modalDismissWithAnimation = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bottom_sheet)
        setupButtons()
        setupStandardBottomSheet()
        //animateStandardBottomSheetStates()
    }

    private fun setupButtons() {
        standardBottomSheetButton.setOnClickListener {
            standardBottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
        }


    }

    private fun setupStandardBottomSheet() {
        standardBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(standardBottomSheet)
        val bottomSheetCallback = object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

            override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
                textView.text = when (newState) {
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED -> "STATE_EXPANDED"
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED -> "STATE_COLLAPSED"
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING -> "STATE_DRAGGING"
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED -> "STATE_HALF_EXPANDED"
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN -> "STATE_HIDDEN"
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING -> "STATE_SETTLING"
                    else -> null
                }
            }

            override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
                val fraction = (slideOffset + 1f) / 2f
                val color = ArgbEvaluatorCompat.getInstance().evaluate(fraction, startColor, endColor)
                slideView.setBackgroundColor(color)
            }
        }
        standardBottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(bottomSheetCallback)
        standardBottomSheetBehavior.saveFlags = BottomSheetBehavior.SAVE_ALL
        textView.setTextColor(textColor)
    }

    private fun showModalBottomSheet() {
        val modalBottomSheet = ModalBottomSheet.newInstance(modalDismissWithAnimation)
        modalBottomSheet.show(supportFragmentManager, ModalBottomSheet.TAG)
    }

    private fun animateStandardBottomSheetStates() {
        standardBottomSheet.postDelayed({
            standardBottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN
        }, 1000L)
        standardBottomSheet.postDelayed({
            standardBottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
        }, 2000L)
        standardBottomSheet.postDelayed({
            standardBottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED
        }, 3000L)
        standardBottomSheet.postDelayed({
            standardBottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
        }, 4000L)
        standardBottomSheet.postDelayed({
            standardBottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN
        }, 5000L)
    }
}
```

ModalBottomSheet.kt

```
class ModalBottomSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private var dismissWithAnimation = false

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.modal_bottom_sheet, container, false)

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        dismissWithAnimation = arguments?.getBoolean(ARG_DISMISS_WITH_ANIMATION) ?: false
        (requireDialog() as BottomSheetDialog).dismissWithAnimation = dismissWithAnimation
    }

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "ModalBottomSheet"
        private const val ARG_DISMISS_WITH_ANIMATION = "dismiss_with_animation"
        fun newInstance(dismissWithAnimation: Boolean): ModalBottomSheet {
            val modalBottomSheet = ModalBottomSheet()
            modalBottomSheet.arguments = bundleOf(ARG_DISMISS_WITH_ANIMATION to dismissWithAnimation)
            return modalBottomSheet
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you assign to $material_version a value in your gradle scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$material_version"
```

to this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'
```

or add `$material_version` parameter to your *build.gradle* file